# Java enum instance inherit from other instance in same enum

Tags: java, enums, polymorphism

Consider an enum like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {

    REACT_TO_EVERYTHING,
    REACT_TO_MOST {
        @Override
        public void method1() {}
    }, REACT_TO_SOME {
        @Override
        public void method1() {}
        @Override
        public void method2() {}
    }, REACT_TO_NOTHING {
        @Override
        public void method1() {}
        @Override
        public void method2() {}
        @Override
        public void method3() {}
    };

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Stack");
    }

    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("Overflow");
    }
}
```

This implementation would be much more DRY when `REACT_TO_SOME` would extend `REACT_TO_MOST` and similarly when `REACT_TO_NOTHING` would extend `REACT_TO_SOME`.
Does Java allow this in any way?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do in the overridden method? And why do you think the inheritance is required here. Can you explain your usecase?

Comment: The goal is, like in the example, to make methods do nothing. A usecase would be logging where your class has a single logger which can be either a TraceLogger or an ErrorLogger, etc. All loggers implement the full set of methods (trace, debug, info, warn, error) and only TraceLogger implements all of them. All implementations one level up will override the relevant method(s) from the 1-level-less logger, replacing them with a do-nothing method. Since there are only as much actual Loggers as there are loglevels, I would like to put them in an enum.

Comment: is each method1 the same?